# Creating a skewed dummy dataset

Tags: r, dummy-data

In order to test out some strategies for removing outliers from laboratory data I want to create a dummy dataset that is a combination of a normal curve and a skewed normal curve.  This is to replicate the situation where my data is a combination of true (good) duplicates and duplicates where one of the points is incorrect to varying amounts.

I can use rnorm to create the good data but how to I introduce skewness to produce the doubtful data?

Thank you.

Comment: Google "skew normal R" -- it looks like the `rsn` function from the `sn` package is what you want.

Comment: Ah.  Thank you.  I had Googled a variety of dummy dataset skewed combinations but hadn't found sn.  Have now.